# Docker: Error, Container command 'docker-entrypoint.sh' not found or does not exist

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My docker-compose.yml is:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8007:8007
  volumes:
    - ~/wpme/wptest/wp_html:/var/www/html

wordpress_db:
  image: mysql
  ports:
    - 3316:3316
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

The command that i run on terminal is:

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

The error that I get:

```
Error, Container command 'docker-entrypoint.sh' not found or does not exist.
```

What's happening? (I'm on ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `docker-entrypoint.sh` was using Windows instead of Unix line endings.
Converting the file to `\n` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It means one of your containers in their dockerfile have a command either on entrypoint or cmd that calls docker-entrypoint.sh and doesnt finds it.

Comment: I checked but no, not even hidden

Comment: can you check the dockerfile ? for a CMD or ENTRYPOINT command

Comment: my docker file is empty